# Need a clarification about 'node' field on the root query type described in GraphQL Global Object Identification Specification

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am checking GraphQL Global Object Identification Specification and found following:

```
To provide options for GraphQL clients to elegantly handle for caching and 
data refetching GraphQL servers need to expose object identifiers in a standardized way. 
In the query, the schema should provide a standard mechanism for asking for an object by ID.
```

and later they provide requirement:

```
Refetching the object is done with the `node` field on the root query object.
```

If I understand this correctly, they expect to have schema like this:

```
type Query {
   node(id: ID!)
}
```

And my question is: how should I understand what exactly object they are referring to?
I have relational database and plenty of tables. Should I scan each of them to find object with that id?

Or id should already contains the information about object type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm interested in the same

Comment: @RichEBee You need to have compound id, that consists of a type of entity and its id. For example 'User:1'. You can parse it, and understand what to do next. Somebody tells that id should be encoded with base64. But that is up to you.